# Rotate screen shortcut on Fedora 27

Tags: fedora, x11, xrandr, display

I've been trying to create a shortcut to rotate the display, but  the command I put (`xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --rotate left`) into the shortcut does not do anything. I opened a terminal and typed it there, nothing happened. Using `--verbose` shows:

```
[suppboii@yoboi ~]$ xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --rotate left --verbose
screen 0: 320x200 84x52 mm  96.09dpi
```

`xrandr -q` shows:

```
[suppboii@yoboi ~]$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1366x768      59.80 +
```

I checked access using `xhost` and got:

```
[suppboii@yoboi ~]$ xhost
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
SI:localuser:root
SI:localuser:suppboii
```

I also added to my xorg.conf over at `/etc/X11/` the following

```
Option "RandRRotation"    "True"
```

and I am currently using the intel `Driver`, vesa did the same.

No success.

I am running Fedora 4.14.11-300.fc27 on a ThinkPad T440p with an i5 4200m and Intel Integrated Graphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by logging into fedora with the option `GNOME on Xorg` in the login screen after booting.